# FTP upload using MVC

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ftp

I am having this error "Unable to upload the specified file. Please check your path.". The file is uploading in my local and to my SQL database but I don't know why it is not uploading on my remote path.

anyway this is what I want to happen, I want to upload the file to my database and to my remote path, having a copy on my local is not really necessary because I can't find other reference code.

can you check if what is wrong with my codes?

**Controller**

```
function upload_gen048()
{

$data['filedate']=$this->input->post('fiil');
//print_r ($data);

$this->load->model('navi_model');
$query = $this->navi_model->upload_gen048($data);

    $this->file_path = realpath(navi_ups.'/gen048');
    $config['upload_path'] = $this->file_path;
    $config['max_size'] = 0;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt';
    //$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $data['upload'] = $this->upload->data();
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');


    if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('uploadData'))
        {   
                $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->ftp->close();
        }
    else { 
            //else, set the success message

                $this->load->library('ftp');
                $config['hostname'] = '000.000.00.102';
                $config['username'] = '***ana';
                $config['password'] = '***ana123_';
                $config['debug']    = TRUE;

                $this->ftp->connect($config);
                $this->ftp->upload(navi_ups. '/gen048','Y:/FTP/RMT', 'auto', 0775);
                $data = array('msg' => "Upload success!");
                $this->ftp->close();                


        }
}
```

**Model**

```
function upload_gen048($data)
{

$x = explode('.',$data['filedate']);

//print_r ($data);

$qString = "";
$qString .= '[dbo].[gen048upload] '; //STORED PROCEDURE
$qString .= "'" .$data['filedate']."'";
//echo $qString;
$query = $this->db->query($qString);
print_r($query->result());
return ($query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result() : NULL);
}
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[gen048upload]
(
        @fileDate VARCHAR(20)

)

AS BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @sql varchar(8000),@sourceTable varchar(500), @dynamic varchar(8000), @tablesuffix varchar(10)
select @tablesuffix=upper(substring(datename(m,convert(datetime,@fileDate)),1,3))+convert(varchar,year(convert(datetime,@fileDate)))
print @tablesuffix


 declare @currmonth varchar(10)
 select @dynamic=''


create table #logs(
i int identity(1,1),
tableName varchar(50),
status varchar(30)
)

set @sourceTable ='gen_048_'+@tablesuffix
insert into #logs(tableName,status) select @sourceTable,'CREATED'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = @sourceTable)
BEGIN
    set @sql = '
    CREATE TABLE '+@sourceTable+'
    (
        [flag] [int] NULL,
        [accname] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [accdate] [varchar](25) NULL,
        [uname] [varchar](255) NULL,        
        [accnum] [varchar](255) NULL,
    )
    '               
    print @sql
    exec (@sql)

    -- '+@dynamic+' if @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN update #logs set status='ERROR' where tableName=@sourceTable END




    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    CREATE TABLE #temp (WHOLEROW VARCHAR(8000))

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temp

    CREATE TABLE #temp1 (WHOLEROW VARCHAR(8000))

    BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @SQL2 = 'BULK INSERT #temp1
        FROM ''Y:\FTP\RMT\' + @fileDate + '.txt' + '''
        WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''char'', KEEPNULLS, FIRSTROW=1, MAXERRORS=0, ROWTERMINATOR =  ''' + CHAR(0x0A) + ''')'

        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL2
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, I just include that because it is in the suggested tags

Comment: Are you sure that the `$config['upload_path']` exists and you have permission to write into that folder?

Comment: yes the $config['upload_path'] is my local and that part is working properly, and yes I also have a permission to write on my remote path because I can manually upload files there.